# Google search results not showing my events rich snippets but does in test tool

Tags: google, google-search-console, googlebot, google-rich-snippets-tool

When I search on "tennessee basketball tournaments", I see my result, but my events dont show up.  I believe I did everything right since this is an ajax page, but I tell Google that `_escaped_fragment_` tag to get the real results.  You can see the result below in my screenshot that it is working, but real results dont show this.  My page has `<meta name="fragment" content="!">` at the very top, and my sitemap uses the cananical URL with the escape fragment.

[Tennesse Basketball Tournaments](https://exposurebasketballtournaments.com/youth-basketball-tournaments/tennessee?_escaped_fragment_=)

**Structured Data Testing Tool**

[image: Structured Data Testing Tool]

**Search Results**

[image]

Comment: My first question is, how long has it been since you put the rich snippets on your site? It can take 30-60 days for Google to notice and update the index. Even then, Google does not guarantee that rich snippets will show up. It is a reasonable expectation of course. It just may take longer than you expected.

Comment: Over a year and a half

Answer (score 1):

I have the same "problem". I also use rich snippets and it shows in test tool but on in Google serp. I guess this is the reason (copy & paste from Google)

> If you've added structured data for rich snippets, but they are not appearing in search results, the problem can be caused by two types of issues:
>   1.) Technical issues with the structured data markup or with the Google’s ability to crawl, index, and utilize the structured data.
>   2.) **Quality issues, that is, structured data that is technically correct, but does not adhere to Google’s quality guidelines.**

So i guess there is a "quality" issues with your website or Google think it's not really important.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this qualifies as an answer, but here goes.

[image]

How is that for an answer?

I do not know if this is the same page, I did a search using site: with tennessee basketball tournaments. I added youth to the list to make things easier.

If this is the same page, then there you go! If it is not, you have a working example to check against to make sure that you are at least consistent.

Comment: Not same page that is all states!

Comment: I would be using the page that appears to be working and compare it to the page that is not working. I find that often it is a small thing that makes the HTML out of balance (lack of a better term) thus effecting the results. I assume there has to be a difference. Have you tried to use Google Webmaster Tools to get Google to fetch that page again? I know it has been a long time, but if I found no difference between the pages, I would try this and have it add it to the index. This appears to be immediate and the SERPs can be checked right away. This can be a good tool for debugging.