# Rich snippets created via AJAX not shown in Webmaster tools

Tags: google-search-console, ajax, rich-snippets, crawlable-ajax

I have a page with rich snippets. On here I load the reviews via AJAX. However, when I test that page in Google Webmaster tools I get:

`Error: If count is specified in review aggregate, page should contain reviews. Otherwise you may want to use votes.`

I have added this `<meta name="fragment" content="!">` to my page as described here https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started

I checked here [Google search results not showing my events rich snippets but does in test tool](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/60784/google-search-results-not-showing-my-events-rich-snippets-but-does-in-test-tool)
But there at least the data shows up in the tests.

How can I make my review data appear in both Google Webmaster Tools and Google SERPs?

Comment: I suspect that rich snippets and crawlable AJAX are not compatible.